# Confusing: Should blank space be taken as character when editing post?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Yesterday, I found a problem when I edited someone's post. The post contained some code, which was not indented well.

So I modified the post to add 4 blank spaces before each line of the code, all together there were about 20 blank spaces that I added.

But when I submitted my modification, Stack Overflow told me that I should modify more than 5 characters, which shocked me after having added 20 blank spaces. Are blank spaces not characters? But C language told me that they are.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are **bigger**, **more important** things to improve in a post other than the code's formatting style.

Did you check the question for correct spelling?  Was there correct grammar and sentence structure?  Does it read well (as in, if you read it out loud, does it make some sense)?

If your edits *only* focus on the code, then they really *are* too simple.  Adding whitespace doesn't count, and *shouldn't* count towards the 5 character minimum.

Comment: Approve. You are right. We should let ourselves concentrate on some important issues. Lifetime is so short.—_—

Comment: -1 because code that isn't formatted at all (as is often the case) or code that has the first and last line or two broken (as also often happens) is far less readable. Adding whitespaces in to fix that is more valid than adding or removing four asterisks for bolding.

Comment: I disagree on your valuation of spelling over formatting when writing questions directly related to coding. code snippet legibility relies heavily on indentation, and improperly formatted code will receive far less attention from potential help than one with a couple spelling errors would.

Comment: @LOLslowSTi:  The way I've always seen it, if the question is actually good and worth answering, then the code formatting is a minor detail.  If the question contains a ton of typos or misspellings, that makes it harder for me to understand what's being asked.  My main point is that edits to make the code better when there's clear and egregious grammar errors elsewhere is not a good use of review resources, and that one should look to improve more than the code style of a post.  Besides...nowadays, I just copy the code into my IDE to run it anyhow and that makes it more readable.

Comment: I still disagree. I have myself scanned right past questions with badly formatted code, to give attention to the next guy who took the time for me to be able to read it better. OP was however implying on edits where there are no grammatical or spelling errors present, and needs to change some 5 characters for his formatting to be accepted as a valid edit. I have been in the same situation as well. Had to cancel my edit after refactoring about 100 lines of code only to realize that it wont recognize it as a valid edit.

Comment: I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree.  I'm not fishing for a reason to not answer a question based on how its code looks; I want to evaluate it based on what is actually being asked.  The actual English portion of the question goes a long(er) way towards that understanding as opposed to blocks of well-formatted code.  After all, a question that contains immaculate styled code could still be off-topic if it's unclear or overly broad.

Comment: There are languages like Python where the code's formatting style makes a huge difference. If a code is wrongly indented in Python, it will lead to unexpected results and/or errors. In questions, this may not need to be edited since the wrong code formatting may be the reason why the question is asked, but in answers, this should absolutely be edited.